# Saving Color Changer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, scripting, 3d

I have this code setup which allows me to change the color of my player. In Unity tester when I hit play I can change my player's color and change between scenes with that color saved just fine but when I build my project I can only change color in the player customization menu and when I change scenes I get equipped the default color.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomizeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] headColors;
    public Material headMat;

    public void ChangeHeadColor(int colorIndex)
    {
        headMat.color = headColors[colorIndex];
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HeadColor", colorIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: To maintain your color after you stop the Unity player you will need to call OnStart() the ChangeHeadColor and pick the last saved color. The code you showed us does not call ChangeHeadColor at all. No wonder it does not work.

Comment: alright, I will try for sure

Comment: hey since the other guy that wanted to help me hasnt replied yet, I would like to ask your help if you are still available. Just hit me up on discord since it is easier for me to get notified (MpamphsFlou001#0054). If not send me a message here and  I will try to reply asap

Comment: I don't know what discord is. Can you please share more code. For instance where do you call the Method ChangeHeadColor() ?

Comment: This is the full script I have made without these two lines
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HeadColor", colorIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
I have attached it to an empty game object and it created this https://imgur.com/Igb8dhV . I also followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5jOAKb_heQ&list=PLBIb_auVtBwDqaEUD_Fs-ZjdUN3bMGqVU&index=6

Comment: Yes but where do you call it. Additionally if you stop the application you do not get the stored values from PlayerPrefs. You should check if PlayerPrefs has key. Ith thats the case than get the value and set that. Otherwise you open the application for the first time.

Comment: since I am kind of a noobie and new to this I have absolutely no idea of what you are talking about. I dont know what you mean by "where do you call it" and PlayerPrefs has ''key'? Like what key? Sorry if I am putting you into too much trouble '

Comment: I will send you the whole project if it fits lol

Comment: No need mate just install anydesk and i fix it in front of you.

Comment: Is it ok that I do not trust these kind of programs? Like I would prefer it if you didnt have access to my whole computer if thats okay. Can I send the project to your email instead?

Comment: is there maybe another way of doing this? An email sounds good to me if you approve

Comment: I have also made it so that when you click player customization button it wont redirect you anywhere. Make sure to check the scene on build settings and make an on click event. Forgot about it but I am sure that you would have found either way

Comment: More or less. If you have the same script it is bot needed .

Comment: wdym? I don't get it

Comment: Do you have the same CustomizeColors script attached in all the scenes or you use something else?

Comment: no, the script that has the code you sent me is only in the customization menu scene. Should I attach the ColorChanger object along with the script in every scene and choose the colors and the playermat again? (did you understood what I said?)

Comment: Yes attach the script in all the scenes you need the same behaviour.

Comment: alright sure. Appreciate it once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start please delete your PlayerPrefs.cs script because it intervenes with UnityEngine. This should work:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomizeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] Colors;
    public Material Mat;


    public void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HeadColor"))
        {
            Mat.color = Colors[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HeadColor")];
            Debug.Log("works");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeColor(int colorIndex)
    {
        Mat.color = Colors[colorIndex];
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HeadColor", colorIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: ty <3 let me try

Comment: Make sure your buttons do have the ChangeColor function (OnClick())

Comment: it works!! Thank you kind man you solved my mystery. Have a nice day!

Comment: If it helped than mark it as a solution please. That's how it works around here :D

Comment: sure thing mate

Comment: hi its me again. It stoped working again after changing scenes. I didnt touch the code, I just made the remaining 10 levels. What could have happened? Do I have to load the playermat on Start(); every time I change scenes?

Comment: this is the warning I get. When I click it it opens the script https://imgur.com/NpvILGX

Comment: yes, you have to load the colors OnStart. The warning you get means that some script you assigned to a GameObject ist not assigned anymore. Either delete the Script component or add the needed one

Comment: Hey man its me again! Color changing works as expected but I wanted to ask for a favor once again. Do you have any idea on how to make it so that each button applies a hat to the player and hides all of the other hats with a script. I have managed to add multiple on click events just so that it can hide all of the hats expect the one I want to show but I couldn't manage to get it to save to other scenes as well (no c# was created for this). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you show here is not complete. If you want to get saved color you can use `PlayerPrefs.GetInt()` in the `Start()` function. As I say i can help you if you update your question and show us full code of class that you use to select color on start.